# Select all rows with specified month date

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a table maintaining record of all reservations made. Now the start date and end date are stored in the following format in this table:

> Start date: DD/MM/YYYY e.g. 20/01/2011 for 20th january

Same format for end date of reservation. 
Now what I need to do is provide a a month based calendar that is for example nov, oct, jan without specific day dates. If any selected, the query the database for all stored dates within this month and display them in list.

I am using java so preparedStatemetn and Statement currently. Any idea how this can be done? the biggest challenge I am facing is matching and selecting the date from user input with the format I have now.
P.s. I am using Oracle SQL
Thanks and really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type of your column is `DATE` then there is no format. If it is a varchar2, however, you should be able to cast it to a date:

```
select to_date(start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') from mytable;
```

If you wanted all dates in October 2011 you could use:

```
select * from mytable where trunc(start_date,'MM') = to_date('01/Oct/2011','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

(assuming start_date is type `DATE`).

Comment: This solution would prevent any index on `start_date` from being used by the optimizer.

Comment: You can easily add a function-based index to the field, such as: `create index trunc_start_date on mytable(trunc(start_date,'MM'));`

Answer (score 1):

I would use range condition on date column:

```
select * from mytable where start_date >= to_date('01/Oct/2011','dd/mm/yyyy') and start_date < to_date('01/Nov/2011','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Using trunc, the oracle planner *should* be able to pick index, however here you specify range for non-modified value.

I'm assuming as John Doyle you have `DATE` format in your table. If you're using VARCHAR2, you're running into extreme performance issues, because full table scan would be needed. If at least the date format would be `yyyy/mm/dd`, then using index would be possible. Consider changing database design to avoid performance problems.